# Email validation only from a list of domains

Tags: java, android, validation, email

I want to validate an email address input via edittext. I've seen the general email validation using Pattern but I have a Arraylist with valid email domains. I want to validate the email address only from this list of domains.

I've tried a lot but could not make it work. Help please :)

**Current Code:**

```
public boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    String regExpn = "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
            + "\\.(abc.com|abc.co|abc.nz|abc.org)$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExpn, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);

    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Thanks

**Original regex for general email validation:**

```
String regExpn = "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
            + "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
            + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\."
            + "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\\.([0-1]?"
            + "[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
            + "([a-zA-Z]+[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: @JaredRummler Hi, I've updated the question. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
(abc\\.com|abc\\.co|abc\\.nz|abc\\.org)
```

instead of

```
\\.(abc.com|abc.co|abc.nz|abc.org)
```

\. is to mean literally a dot and not "every character". \\. is needed for Java to escape the backslash to get \. as regex.

EDIT: Removing \\. in front and escaping the domain dot is sufficient, regex and samples updated:

```
    String regExpn = "^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@"
            + "(abc\\.com|abc\\.co|abc\\.nz|abc\\.org)$";
```

So

```
        System.out.println(isEmailValid("yasd@abcXcom"));
        System.out.println(isEmailValid("yasd@abc.com"));
        System.out.println(isEmailValid("yasd@abc.co"));
        System.out.println(isEmailValid("yasd@abc.org"));
        System.out.println(isEmailValid("yasd@x"));
```

brings

```
false
true
true
true
false
```

Comment: @iitum studant What doesn't work? Can you provide the test method you are using? I did only look at the domain thing not at the regex that I understood you've found elsewhere. Did that regex work before you extended it to your domain list?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question with the original regex which I used to validate general email addresses and it worked perfectly. For the modified one, I used abc@abc.com but it did not work

Comment: I'm not yet used to this interface ... I've edited the regex and sample again. Hope it helps.

Comment: It works. I was adding and extra \\. before (abc.com|abc.co|abc.nz|abc.org). Thanks for the help mate. :)